# Access an ASMX Service Reference in Universal Windows Apps

Tags: windows, web, service, asmx, universal

Can somebody help me with a little issue about Universal Windows Apps?

I'm trying to develop a small universal app that calls an .asmx web service. I can add the Service Reference successfully to the Windows 8.1 project and reference it from the classes in the shared project. When I compile and run the application, it runs without problem.

But when I switch to Windows Phone 8.1, I'm unable to compile and I get an error telling me that the classes generated by the service reference in the Windows 8.1 Project are not accessible from the Shared Project.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FInally I solved this unanswered question. It seems in Universal Windows Apps is not possible to use SOAP Web Services as Service References, so I used REST Services instead.